# jquery - Remove a dynamic word in a text

Tags: jquery

When I user click on the button remove word and as enter 2 in the input box it should remove it from the element id="list"

```
<input type="text" id="word"><input type="button" value="remove word">

<span id="list">1,2,3</span>
```

I did the following on the click event:

```
var text = $('.word').val();
    $('#list').html($('#list').html().replace(/text/ig, ""));
```

I understand it looks for the string text and not the var. So how can I change the syntax to make it search for the var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literal regexps (`/.../`) are literal in such a way that they cannot contain variables. You'd need to construct a regexp this way:

```
var text = $('.word').val();
$('#list').html($('#list').html().replace(new RegExp(text, "ig"), ""));
```

Edit: If you need to have following commas removed, you'd be best off by parsing it as an `Array` and removing the appropriate element:

```
var text = $('.word').val();
var array = $('#list').html().split(","); // split into an Array
                                          // items are delimited by a comma
while(array.indexOf(text) > -1) {         // as long as text is in the array...
    array.splice(array.indexOf(text), 1); // remove one element from the array
                                          // at the position the text is
}
$('#list').html(array.join(","));         // concatenate the elements with a
                                          // comma again
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = $('.word').val();
    $('#list').html($('#list').html().replace(new Regexp(text, "ig"), ""));
```

Comment: Please note though that JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes thanks...works great...Also sorry if I didn't explain properly but when I remove a item from the list the comma will still be there so I'm looking for a function to remove the item from the list comma included?

Comment: @Yannick: I added your extra need in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code, here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gk5pV/ . Documentation is inline:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#replaceButton").click(function() {
        // find the word
        var text = $('#word').val();

        // create a regex
        var re = new RegExp(text, "gi");

        // replace the inner html
        // please note: this may cause serious problems when not used on textnodes
        // see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery
        var replacedHTML = $('#list').html().replace(re, "");

        // replace
        $('#list').html(replacedHTML);
    });
});
```